# Kohana Models - Can I use subfolder to organize?

Tags: kohana

I'm using Kohana and I have several models in the Models folder of my application.  Can I organize those models into subfolders and call them in a way that Kohana can find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can with Kohana 3:

I have a file '**item.php**' inside '**application/classes/model**' which holds the class '**Model_Item**'.

If you want to go deeper, you just have to add the directory names in the classname:

The file '**item.php**' inside '**application/classes/model/super/folder**' which holds the class '**Model_Super_Folder_Item**'.
An easy way to be able to keep you from typing the whole class-name is by extending the class with a big name:

'**item.php**' inside '**application/classes/model**' which holds the class '**Model_Item**' which extends '**Model_Super\Folder_Item**'.

I'm not sure if this is possible with Kohana 2.x. I went straight to using Kohana3 and skipped 2.x (almost) completely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it .

Consider the case in different way .If you have table with name **`user_images`** then you should create the model file with name **`image`** and place it inside **`model/user/image`**
as    also the table's primary key is not  **`id`**  its **`image_id`**

```
 class Model_User_image extends ORM 
{
   protected $_primary_key = 'image_id';   
}
```